# hide button onmouseenter isn't triggering

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent

My onmouseenter function isn't triggering.

I created a button that would allow you to go to the top. However, once there I want the button to have a display property of none. I tried doing it in two ways. One with classList and the other with style.display = 'none'. Both didn't work, am I missing something in the logic ?

EDIT-------------
onmouseleave the button should reappear. I added the function.

Here is a code pen

```js
const topDiv = document.getElementById('topDiv')
const arrowup = document.getElementById('arrowup')

const hideArrow = () => {
  if (topDiv) {
    arrowup.classList.remove(showme');
    arrowup.classlist.add('hideme');

  } else {
    arrowup.classList.add('showme');
  }

}

 

  const showArrow = () => {
  if (!topDiv) {
    arrowup.classList.remove('hideme');
    arrowup.classList.add('showme');
  } 
}
```

```css
#top {
  height: 1000px;
}

a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}

.showme {
  display: block;
}

.hideme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseleave="showArrow() onmouseenter="hideArrow()" id="top">
  hello
</div>


<a class="showme" id="arrowup" onClick="hideArrow()" href="#top">
  click me
</a>
```

Comment: First thing, `top` is a bad variable name because `window.top` is a property. `return ` is going to only run `arrowup.classList.remove = 'showme';` It does not run `arrowup.classlist.add ='hideme';` There is no reason for the returns in your code.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Here is a codepen - https://codepen.io/shar27-the-encoder/pen/XWZOxgJ?editors=1111

Comment: Don't change the question, while is answered!

Comment: You still have a return in your code in the codepen. Still not sure what you are expecting with that if/else

Comment: you changed the ID ``top`` in the script to ``topDiv`` but not in the html...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues:

- `onmouseenter="hideArrow"` is missing brackets -> `onmouseenter="hideArrow()"`
- `add` and `remove` are functions, that get the class as param -> `add('showme')`
- the return is wrong -> remove it

**Working example:**

```js
const topDiv = document.getElementById('topDiv')
const arrowup = document.getElementById('arrowup')

const hideArrow = () => {
  if (topDiv) {
    arrowup.classList.remove('showme');
    arrowup.classList.add('hideme');
  } 
  else {
    arrowup.classList.add('showme');
  }
}
```

```css
#top {
  height: 1000px;
}

a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
}

.showme {
  display: block;
}

.hideme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseenter="hideArrow()" id="topDiv">
  hello
</div>

<a class="showme" id="arrowup" onClick="hideArrow()" href="#topDiv">
  click me
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked The else condition was there so the button would reappear after leaving however it seems, in this case, it didn't work. I created a separate function and added it to the code and added onmouseleave to the di.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the return keyword from the if condition because it causes the function to stop running at that point
2. element.classList.add() is a function while you are assigning classes to the element using the '=' operator. So the correct way to do it is `arrowup.classList.add('hideme')` and `arrowup.classList.remove('showme')`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Still doesn't work. Please check out this code pen https://codepen.io/shar27-the-encoder/pen/XWZOxgJ?editors=1111